# Simulated chatbot that switches input methods?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a chatbot I created that asks for a user's username, then stores it as a variable. However, in one of my dialog trees, I have to ask the user for them to type another answer, I have it working so that user's can navigate via button clicks.

On username capture, the "input bar" is removed from controls and I append buttons with each message function. I tried to do the inverse of this (remove buttons and add an input) which does work, however I can't get my input to do anything. It won't submit on enter, it won't save a variable and in my trial and error, I found that if I try to set a var off that msg value, it updates the username's.

**Here is my function to retrieve name**

```
function get_username() {
  send_msg("Hello I'm Mumbles, the Help Bot", function(){
    send_msg("Who am I speaking with today?")
  });
}

function ai(msg) {
  if (username.length < 3) {
    username = msg;
          send_msg("Nice to meet you"+username+". What are you working on today?" , function() {
            $("#controls").append(
              '<button class="options one" value="my_certifications" type="button">My Certifications</button>' +
                '<button class="options one" value="videos"type="button">Videos</butto/>' +
                '<button class="options one" value="login"type="button">Login</butto/>' +
                '<button class="options one" value="other"type="button">Other</butto/>' 
            );
          });
        }
      // Remove text bar
      $("#controls").empty();

};
```

**Here is my function to try and capture email**

```
    } else if (b_val == "my_practicum") {
      send_msg("What is the email address you submitted your practicum with? By having this we can give you a status update!" , function() {
            $("#controls").append(
                      '<textarea id="message" class="practicum-bar" placeholder="Type Your Name - Then Hit Enter"></textarea><button style="display:none;" id="sendMsg">Send</button>'                  );
                 email = msg;
        console.log(email);
      });
    } 
}
```

If you want to see this in action, here my **[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/umqmm9s9/).** You can see it by going through this user path

> Enter name > Certifications > My Practicum > Enter email

Any help on this is appreciated! Thanks!

Comment: what do you want to happen after entering email

Comment: @jackblank It would ask a follow up question (not yet put into the example) while it runs an api function. I just need to be able to store it as a variable

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you remove `controls`  by doing `$("#controls").empty();` and you want to add an event to a dynamically created element so you have to add the context to the second parameter of the `.on`.  look now [you can see the console.log in the fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/umqmm9s9/1/) the second time you clicked enter because jquery can detect the item now.

```
$("#controls").on("keypress", "#message", function(event){

 if (event.which == 13) {
      console.log("my test");
      if ($("#slideThree").prop("checked")) {
         $("#sendMsg").click();
         event.preventDefault();
         //*edit you can now change variables outside of scope*
      }
  } 
});
```

now you can do your event handling.